# yaourt curl error: SSL connect error

Tags: arch-linux, yaourt

I'm trying to install some packages form `yaourt`.

For example :

```
yaourt compiz
```

But it gets me following error:

```
[hamed@localhost ~]$ yaourt compiz
curl error: SSL connect error
```

Please tell me what's wrong with `yaourt`?

Comment: Apparently, your government doesn't want you accessing the AUR.

Comment: I don't think so. Because I can open this link https://aur.archlinux.org and download packages.

Comment: Another Iranian user has complained about this in the past. Either install from AUR manually or, if you want to keep using `yaourt`, use a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem apparently occurs for Iranian people.

**The Solution :**

You have to replace `yaourt-ssl3` and `package-query-ssl3` instead `yaourt` and `package-query`.

Firstly you need to uninstall current `yaourt` and `package-query` by following command :

```
sudo pacman -Rsc package-query
```

And then install `ssl3` :

```
curl -O3 https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pa/package-query-ssl3/package-query-ssl3.tar.gz
tar -xf package-query-ssl3.tar.gz
cd package-query-ssl3
makepkg -cis
cd ..
curl -O3 https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ya/yaourt-ssl3/yaourt-ssl3.tar.gz
tar -xf yaourt-ssl3.tar.gz
cd yaourt-ssl3
makepkg -cis
```

That's it.